# irb access pre-load script local variables

Tags: ruby, irb

i'm using `irb -I . -r script.rb` to `require` a script before starting an interactive session.  functions defined in the global scope are available but variables aren't unless they are declared with `@`

is there a way to access local variables defined in the global context of a script or a better way to do this

---

*script.rb*:

```
def func() "..." end
a = "str"
@b = 1
```

then after `irb` starts:

```
irb(main):001:0> a

NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

irb(main):002:0> @b

=> 1

irb(main):003:0> func

=> "..."
```

i'm assuming that the script's contents are executed as if defined in a function (eg: `main` in C-type languages) and so the variables at the global context are local variables that are not accessible outside that scope

so do most people use `@` variables when writing their scripts?

the use-case is narrow in scope (script development) and the solution is trivial (search-replace any `variable` with `@variable`), but I'm learning the semantics of the language and I'm curious about this.  Can't the [execution context](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html) be exposed and merged into the current context somehow?

Comment: `-r` loads the library using `require` and according to [its documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require): *"local variables will not be propagated to the loading environment."*.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, I'm looking through the docs now for some kind of "with binding" functionality, otherwise I"ll try to write something to expose the binding to the irb session

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't access local variables from a different scope. That's the *whole point* of local variables: they are local to the scope they are defined in.

In this case, `a` is local to the script body of `script.rb`.

Comment: I agree that the purpose of local variables is to separate that context from the calling context and avoid pollution, etc..  Im looking for some kind of meta-programming solution more for understanding than for actual production usage

Comment: no offense but I must offend. if you are unclear on local vs global scope (which your question proves) your quest for understanding starts there, meta programming magic is for after you build your lightsaber.

Comment: @engineerDave yeah well i'm kinda new to Ruby. in javascript the global context is the same in a script and in an interactive node session.

Comment: yeah everything is pretty much global in JS LOL but scope is important in ruby because of things like Proc and lamdas, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `binding.irb` is what you are looking for.

*script.rb*:

```
def func() "..." end
a = "str"
@b = 1
binding.irb
```

From the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/Binding.html):

> Opens an IRB session where binding.irb is called which allows for
> interactive debugging. You can call any methods or variables available
> in the current scope, and mutate state if you need to.